# Prove that $\text{rank}(T) = \text{rank}([T]_{\beta}^{\gamma})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation between finite-dimensional vector spaces, and let $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be ordered basis for $V$ and $W$, respectively. Then $\text{rank}(T) = \text{rank}([T]_{\beta}^{\gamma})$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Before presenting this theorem, the author defines $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(L_{A})$, where $L_{A}:\textbf{F}^{n}\to\textbf{F}^{m}$ is the linear transformation defined by $L_{A}x = Ax$.

But we know that

$$\text{rank}(L_{A}) = \dim\text{span}\{L_{A}(e_{1}),L_{A}(e_{2}),\ldots,L_{A}(e_{n})\}$$

Moreover, $L_{A}(e_{j}) = a_{j}$, where $a_{j}$ is the $j$-th column of $A$. Consequently, $\text{rank}(A)$ equals the dimension of its column space.

Based on it, I do not know how to proceed. Am I on the right track?

This question has already been solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508227/proving-that-mathrmrankt-mathrmrankl-a-and-mathrmnullityt), but the textbook has not presented the fact that invertible linear mappings preserve rank so far. Is there another way to solve it? Or should I insist a little bit more on [it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508227/proving-that-mathrmrankt-mathrmrankl-a-and-mathrmnullityt)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Exercise.** Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ two finite dimensional vector spaces over the same field. Then, if $f : V_1 \to V_2$ is a linear isomorphism, for any subspace $S$ of $V_1$, $f(S)$ is a subspace of $V_2$ such that $\dim f(S) = \dim S$.

Once you are proved this simple exercise, suppose $\beta = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and $\gamma = \{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$. Define $\phi_\beta : V \to \mathbf F^n$ by
$$\phi_\beta \Big( \sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i \Big) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n
\end{pmatrix},$$
and similarly for $\phi_\gamma : W \to \mathbf F^m$. It is easy to see that $\phi_\beta$ and $\phi_\gamma$ are linear isomorphisms and that the following diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V @>{T}>> W\\
@V{\phi_\beta}VV @VV{\phi_\gamma}V \\
\mathbf{F}^n @>>{L_A}> \mathbf{F}^m
\end{CD} \qquad \textrm{where } A := [T]_\beta^\gamma
$$
commutes, that is, $\phi_\gamma \circ T = L_A \circ \phi_\beta$. Then, if we take $V_1 = \mathbf F^m$, $V_2 = W$, $f = \phi_\gamma^{-1}$ and $S = L_A(\mathbf F^n)$ in the preceding exercise, $\phi_\gamma^{-1}(L_A(\mathbf F^n))$ is a subspace of $W$ with the same dimension of $L_A(\mathbf F^n)$, i.e., with dimension $\operatorname{rank}(A)$. But also, since $\phi_\beta$ is surjective, $\mathbf F^n = \phi_\beta(V)$, and then
$$\phi_\gamma^{-1}(L_A(\mathbf F^n)) = \phi_\gamma^{-1}(L_A(\phi_\beta(V))) = T(V).$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It has helped me to grasp the details.